# Jubula Functional Testing Tool toolkit?

Tags: eclipse, toolkit, jubula

I am new to Jubula.Struggling hard to understand the flow of Jubula.
1)can anyone tell me what is the difference between jubula's toolkits (**RCP,SWING,SWT,javafx**)??

Comment: This is far to broad. All these things are easy to research, you can start just by reading the tags here on SO - [tag:rcp] [tag:swing] [tag:swt] [tag:javafx]

Answer (score 0):

These are the user interface technologies supported by it; your AUT needs to be written using one of these technologies in order to be able to test it with Jubula.

They are all bundled with the default installation and you can choose between them when creating a new project.

Comment: thank you, but can you tell me more about these technologies?

Comment: I'm not allowed to. You can only ask something on StackOverflow after you invested a reasonable time on research.